# Wamp server installation issue in window 8.1

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp, windows-8.1

After install the wamp server in my system (windows 8.1 64-bit). The Aestan Tray menu turn green after taking 5 minutes from orange color.

However myphpadmin or localhost or 127.0.0.1 are not opening.

I have uninstalled my skype and re-installed the wamp server still i have the same issue...

I also checked the ISS in the control panel (Turn windows feature on or off) it is also not set.

Since i have start the apache service and test port 80..

i have getting the message:

> Your port 80 is not actually used
>
> Press Enter to Exit

Some time I get the message error message when Aestan Tray blink orange:

> Could not execute menu item (internal error) [Exception] Could not
>   perform service action: An instance of the service is already running

I have installed wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-64b

In my office system (window 7) wamp server is working fine. i have installed without any issues.

I already done so many things to correct it from the instruction available from internet.

I have already installed/uninstall wamp server by 12-15 times.

Please help me to sort this issue.

Comment: I have never seen the WAMPServer icon `blink orange`. Can I suggest you read this post on the WAMPServer forum and make sure you have all the correct MSCV Runtime libraries installed. [WampServer Forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123608)

Comment: The Aestan Tray menu turn green... Still my phpmyadmin or localhost is not connecting...

Comment: check your hosts file `c:\windows\system32\srivers\etc\hosts` it should contain `127.0.0.1 localhost` and `::1 localhost` thats 2 lines